# How to customize icons near the scrollbar in the Eclipse Java editor?

Tags: eclipse

The Eclipse java editor displays small colored rectangle icons just to the right of the scrollbar to indicate lines with //TODOs, deprecated statements, etc.  One of the most useful shows the other occurrences of a currently selected variable, but the color of this one is practically the same as the background.

What are these icons called and how can I customize the colors?

[image: icons in eclipse IDE near editor scrollbar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like a lot of things in Eclipse, it's easy, once you know what something is called ;-)

In the Preferences tree, that right strip is the "Overview Ruler".  Here's some of my notes:

```
Display of Task and Bookmarks
    Preferences / General / Editors / Text Editors / Annotations
    Show in:
        Vertical Ruler = left edge icons, in sight of current scroll position
        Overview Ruler = right edge colored blocks, relative to overall file
        Text as = markup the actual text
```

Comment: Yes, the name is everything.  I just learned this trick: right click on the overview ruler- the context menu will go right to the correct prefs screen.

Comment: too bad one can't change color of the annotation in the vertical rules...?